# Codeception-style reporting for Behat

Tags: testing, automated-tests, bdd, codeception, behat

Does anybody know if there's a way to have test reports for Behat similar to what we could have for Codeception?

I mean, Behat with `pretty` format output just gives us steps from feature files. Whereas Codeception reports exact request body with headers and also reports responses.

Is there any way to have similar reports for Behat? Maybe some extension or plugin? I did a search but didn't find anything similar.

Comment: Have you tried to run codeception with --steps parameter?

Comment: @Naktibalda I need behat to generate report similar to codeception.

Comment: Ah, I misread the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the plugin you are looking for: [dutchiexl/BehatHtmlFormatterPlugin](https://github.com/dutchiexl/BehatHtmlFormatterPlugin)

This generates HTML reports from your test results:

[image]

You can drill down in this report to get feature or scenario level data as required.

Any step within `Context` methods that you `echo` content out it will appear within the information you can drill down into... at the scenario level you can then expand the step and see it.  So you will need to add that in order to see that information.

Answer (score 0):

Behat is a generic TDD framework and does not know anything about web requests by default. You could easily use it for unit testing in your application or for testing some CLI application.

So, if you need extended information on requests during the step failures, you have to:

1. Provide Behat with those Request/Response objects
2. Customize Behat behavior in `AfterStep`, `AfterScenario` and/or `AfterFeature` hooks to make use of those Request/Response objects
3. Find or write custom output formatter to output that info

You can see examples of [custom formatters](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-behat/blob/master/src/Allure/Behat/Formatter/AllureFormatter.php) (initially written by yours truly), which are used in Allure reporting tool (worth giving it a try for rich reporting exprience).